# How to conditionally assign a value to Flutter List

Tags: flutter, list, conditional-statements

How to conditionally assign a value to "ingList" based on the value of recipeList?

```
 class Calculator extends StatefulWidget {
    List<IngredientList> recipeList;
    Calculator(this.recipeList, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Calculator> createState() => _CalculatorState();
}

class _CalculatorState extends State<Calculator> {
  List<IngredientList> ingList = [];
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve? Do you want to copy recipeList to ingList? Or do you want to check double ingredients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `initState` to do that

```dart
class Calculator extends StatefulWidget {
  List<IngredientList> recipeList;
  Calculator(this.recipeList, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Calculator> createState() => _CalculatorState();
}

class _CalculatorState extends State<Calculator> {
  List<IngredientList> ingList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ingList = widget.recipeList; // you can do any condition here
  }
}
```

Comment: like ```ingList = widget.recipeList ?? [] ``` ?

Comment: @Giovanni yes you can do that just make your recipeList can be null for check like that.